# Currency Vue.js filtering Laravel error: Use of undefined constant currency - assumed 'currency'

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, currency

The Vue filter for showing currency is not working. I want to show currencies with Vue.js in my HTML code.

And I got an error:

> Use of undefined constant currency - assumed 'currency' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (0)

My code in `transaksi.js`:

```
 Vue.filter('currency', function (money) {
   return accounting.formatMoney(money, "Rp ", 2, ".", ",")
})
```

And in HTML tag:

```
<td>Rp. {{ $product->price | curency  }}</td>
```

Comment: Hey, did you type "curency " instead of "currency" in your code or you just write it wrong here?

Comment: the problem is solved now... i used @convert($product->price)